# root sign ugly in chrome using jqMath

Tags: jqmath

I changed from using MathJAX to jqMath recently, but I'm having trouble displaying roots with another base than 2:  √^a{b^c}
will display correctly in Firefox:
[image]

But really ugly in Chrome: [image]

This is both on Linux and OS X; have not tried others yet. Anybody got solution for this? Is seems a shame to have it rendering so ugly on Chrome...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't support MathML natively, sigh, so jqMath is not so pretty there. See:

[jqMath: how to improve the display of vectors and super/subscripts on an android app's webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459202/jqmath-how-to-improve-the-display-of-vectors-and-super-subscripts-on-an-android) (this is about android, but the same answer goes for chrome)

[Chrome bug report / discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152430)

Comment: Because in the other answer, you stated that you are the author of jQmath: thank you for your amazing work! I am using jQmath to create "textbooks" about highschool math - it works really well. (Other than in Chrome, that is...:-) )  Is there, to your knowledge, a place to complain to google about this lack in there flagship browser?

Comment: As far as I know, the best place may be in the second link I gave above, "Chrome bug report / discussion". Thanks!

Comment: @DaveBarton, I can't formulate the question long enough for StackOverflow, so I will ask here: how to properly display numbers in scientific notation (`1.2345e+6` will be formatted as `1.2345e + 6`)?

Comment: 1.2345·10^6 (or you can choose a different dot character if you want)